# Can we package the branding files, custom masterpage and custom layouts and upload them to SharePoint using SharePoint framework (SPFx)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Is it possible to package the branding files (CSS, JS, images, ..), custom masterpage and custom layouts and upload them to SharePoint using SharePoint framework (SPFx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharePoint Modern experience does not have a notion of a customizable page layout as of today.
Here is a [documentation tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package) on how to include additional information architecture elements in a SPFx solution (like columns and lists) and here is a [blog post on how to include additional assets](https://vinodscodes.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/how-to-include-javascript-files-in-sharepoint-framework-solutions/) (like JavaScript or CSS files).

Comment: I am using SPFx in classic sites and classic pages because I need to customize the branding. In .wsp solutions we were using “modules “ to upload files to specific paths, is there an alternative here?

Comment: SPFx will allow you to upload files. The classic experience however it will only show up webparts, from SPFx (extensions and ui actions built with SPFx are not supported in classic), and that might be less than ideal for global components. You can always provision things using PnP Provisioning instead.

Comment: SPFx allows to upload files to SharePoint Style library and Masterpages gallery? How we do this?

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226589/provision-files-css-js-with-sharepoint-framework

Comment: Thank you very much, I am trying this solution but this error appears: “property assets is not allowed “, should I add it in a feature?

Comment: if you take a look at the schema, it has to be in a feature indeed. https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json

Comment: Yes, right. I tried it and it is working. Thank you very much for your assistance.